# Sequence of Commands in Sage

Tags: python-2.7, sage

Sage programing

write a sequence of commands that will randomly generate an integer a between 1 and 6 and another integer between 1 and 6 and compute the following:

(a)the sum of the two integers as an integer.

(b) the sum of the two integers as a string.

(c) a string representing the value of a plus b (i.e if a=2 and b=3, the string that should returned is '2+3'

Comment: I'm sorry, but we are not here to do your programming assignments.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Mandatory reading: [ask], [MCVE], [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

that prints all values required:

```
import random

a = random.randint(1,6)
b = random.randint(1,6)

print(a+b)       # sum
print(str(a+b))  # sum as string
print(str(a)+"+"+str(b)) # expression
```

note that 2 first printed statements are identical. Only the type change (int or string).

output:

```
6
6
4+2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: would you be able to help me out with this :                                    Evaluate the following in Sage : 

var('a,b,c')

a=2*b

b=2*c

c=2                                                                                                            b                                                                                                                a

Comment: var('a, b, c')
a=2*b
b=2*c
c=2
b
a
︡(a, b, c)
2*c
2*b

Comment: ?  Just ... evaluate each of these things in Sage.  Do you not have access to Sage?  That would make this assignment be hard to do.